# NativeIO chmod "ENOTDIR" exception in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop

I'm finding that a mapreduce job cant start due to some funniness in the RawLocalFileSystem, it appears.

How can I debug this error ?  It appears that there is no trace of the directory or command which is associated with the NativeIO chmod exception.

One option will be of course to bundle a jar into my classpath with a custom RawLocalFileSystem implementation, but that seems like overkill.

13/07/11 18:39:43 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root cause:ENOTDIR: Not a directory
ENOTDIR: Not a directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.chmod(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execSetPermission(FileUtil.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting bug: It turned out that i indeed had a FILE created which existed, already, in a place where a directory was needed to be created.

That is , some how, I had a file called "tmp" in my file system implementation's root directory !

In any case, the confusion was due to scarce error reporting by the hadoop NativeIO class.

I think it is a failure which should be reported and logged better by the underlying NativeIO class .